# Execute window on load only if class exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in need of executing `$(window).on('load', function()` only if a certain class exists in a DOM element (div).

My current code is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if (window.innerWidth > 767) {
  var $sticky = $('#sticky');
  var $stickyrStopper = $('.footer');
  if (!!$sticky.offset()) { // make sure ".sticky" element exists
    var generalSidebarHeight = $sticky.innerHeight();
    var stickyTop = $sticky.offset().top;
    var stickOffset = 0;
    var stickyStopperPosition = $stickyrStopper.offset().top;
    var stopPoint = stickyStopperPosition - generalSidebarHeight - stickOffset;
    var diff = stopPoint + stickOffset;
    $(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
      var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number
      //////////////
      if (stopPoint < windowTop) {
          $sticky.css({ position: 'absolute', top: diff });
      } else if (stickyTop < windowTop+stickOffset) {
          $sticky.css({ position: 'fixed', top: stickOffset });
      } else {
          $sticky.css({position: 'absolute', top: 'initial'});
      }/////////////
    });
  }
    
  }
});
```

And this is my idea, if the class exists:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if (window.innerWidth > 767) {
                if ($(".classexists")[0]){
```

Where the element would be:

```
<div class="classexists">123</div>
```

Execute `window on load` function before the main function:

```
 $(window).on('load', function() {
```

if class does not exist, do not actually execute a `$(window).on('load', function() {`, just execute the rest of the code normally.

This code is supposed to create a sticky sidebar.

Comment: Do you mean an ES6 class, or a DOM element with the class?

Comment: By "class exists" do you mean that any element has that class or a particlar element has that class? Also you don't "execute window on load"... you can set a handler that the browser will execute when that event comes, but it won't be your code executing it.

Comment: `if ($(".classname").length > 0)`

Comment: If the DOM has a div element with the class, then execute the function.

Comment: Hello, somebody there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understanding your problem correctly, try this:

```
    function example() {
    var $sticky = jQuery('#sticky');
    var $stickyrStopper = jQuery('.footer');
    if (!!$sticky.offset()) { // make sure ".sticky" element exists
        var generalSidebarHeight = $sticky.innerHeight();
        var stickyTop = $sticky.offset().top;
        var stickOffset = 0;
        var stickyStopperPosition = $stickyrStopper.offset().top;
        var stopPoint = stickyStopperPosition - generalSidebarHeight - stickOffset;
        var diff = stopPoint + stickOffset;
        jQuery(window).scroll(function () { // scroll event
            var windowTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop(); // returns number
            //////////////
            if (stopPoint < windowTop) {
                $sticky.css({ position: 'absolute', top: diff });
            } else if (stickyTop < windowTop + stickOffset) {
                $sticky.css({ position: 'fixed', top: stickOffset });
            } else {
                $sticky.css({ position: 'absolute', top: 'initial' });
            }/////////////
        });
    }
}
if (window.innerWidth > 767) {
    if (jQuery('.classexists').length > 0) {
        jQuery(window).on('load', function () {
            example();
        });
    } else {
        example();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

Comment: I did that, but somehow I got a syntax error. I'm going to try your solution.

Comment: Check the update

Comment: don't put the code inside `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` will not work

Comment: I only saw this now........ :(

Comment: This part isn't working: `  if (jQuery('.classexists').length > 0) { jQuery(window).on('load', function () { example(); }); } ` Only what comes after the else statement is working.

Comment: I realized why it's not working. My page loads an external html page, so the code here is not being able to find the element because it is looking for the element before the external html page loads, but that's weird, because there's a window onload function settle.

Comment: if you put the code inside document ready will not if part will not working only else will work